# Using variable in for Loop using seq -w option

Tags: bash, shell, loops, variables, for-loop

I am trying to run a for loop as below without success

```
hour=`date +%H -d "1 Hour Ago"`
cd /Log1/
for i in `seq -w 00 "$hour"`;  // $hour not working
do
zgrep -a "Packet" LOG1.txt| grep "#SUCCESS#" |wc -l >>success_chour.txt
zgrep -a "Packet" LOG2.txt| grep "#FAIL#" |wc -l >>fail_chour.txt
done
```

I have tried `$hour`, `"$hour"`, and `'$hour'` without success.

Comment: This works for me, but you your `//` comment wouldn't. What exactly isn't working? What are you using `i` for?

Comment: + cd /Log1/AL/TTT_Logs/Backup/
+ echo 'Hour: 12'
Hour: 12
++ seq -w 00 12
+ for i in '`seq -w 00 "$hour"`'
+ zgrep -a 'Packet\[FULL' TTT.log.2016-10-09-00.gz
+ grep '#SUCCESS#'
+ wc -l
+ zgrep -a 'Packet\[FULL' TTT.log.2016-10-09-00.gz
+ grep '#FAIL#'
+ wc -l

Comment: Code in comments is very hard to read due to limited formatting in them. Can you [edit] your question to add the relevant information?

Comment: `seq` is not part of bash -- not shipped with the bash codebase, and bash has no control over how it operates; it's also not covered by any POSIX standard. I question, thus, whether this is legitimately a bash question, vs a question about a very specific operating system's implementation of a nonstandardized tool.

Comment: Why don't you describe the behavior you actually want, and we could tell you how to get it without using `seq`?

Comment: BTW, you might find the results of `for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do printf '%02d\n' "$i"; done` informative.

Comment: ...anyhow, what's the point of iterating between 00 and your hour number, if you don't actually *use* the generated value in any way inside your loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jiapingzjp@jiapingzjp-Dell:~$ cat my.sh

```
hour=`date +%H -d "1 Hour Ago"`
for i in `seq -w 00 "$hour"`;
do
  echo $i
done
```

jiapingzjp@jiapingzjp-Dell:~$ bash my.sh

```
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
```

I think the code is OK, I try both `"bash test.sh"` `"dash test.sh"` in ubuntu system, it works fine. Maybe you can show what the error message you get and what the command you run.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what "without success" means in this context, since you're not even *trying* to expand `$i` anywhere inside the body of your loop.

That said, using `seq` is actually not ideal -- it's a nonstandard tool not built into bash. Better to use functionality guaranteed to be available everywhere the shell is:

```
# Calculate both day and hour at once
log_scan_end_time=$(date -d "1 hour ago" '+%Y-%M-%d-%H')

# ...then create log_scan_prefix by removing the hour
log_scan_prefix=${log_scan_end_time%-*}

# and extract the hour alone
max_hour=${log_scan_end_time##*-}

for ((cur_hour=0; cur_hour<max_hour; cur_hour++)); do
  printf -v cur_hour_str '%02d' "$cur_hour" # generate a 0-padded string
  logs=( Packet*"${log_scan_prefix}-${cur_hour_str}"*.gz )
  [[ -e ${logs[0]} ]] || {
    echo "No logs found matching pattern ${logs[0]}" >&2
    continue
  }

  # print a header line in the output file to allow diagnosing results
  for f in success_chour.txt fail_chour.txt; do
    {
      printf '# '
      printf '%q ' "${logs[@]}"
      printf '\n'
    } >>"$f"
  done

  zgrep -E -a --count \
    -e '(Packet.*#SUCCESS#)|(#SUCCESS#.*Packet)' \
    -- /dev/null "${logs[@]}" >>success_chour.txt
  zgrep -E -a --count \
    -e '(Packet.*#FAIL#)|(#FAIL#.*Packet)' \
    -- /dev/null "${logs[@]}" >>fail_chour.txt
done
```